# Active Record and Active Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-relation

What is the difference between active record and active relation in Ruby on rails? Please put the light in very basic terms as i am new to the Ruby on rails and learning it on own.

Comment: http://j.venator.vc/2011/03/01/arel-active-relation-in-rails-3/ http://magicscalingsprinkles.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/why-i-wrote-arel/

Answer (score 0):

I found this video to be a good description:

http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts/rails3/active-relation-active-model

My understanding is that you cannot compare the 2 - ActiveRecord uses ActiveRelation as it's search API ([www.railsdispatch.com/posts/activerelation](http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/activerelation))